# Android - onPause and onResume

Tags: android, android-activity, onresume, onpause

I have code which randomly draws red circles. It didn't work until I had pause and resume methods in BOTH classes. Without the pause and resume methods, the screen would just be black and not change. Why did I need an `onPause` and `onResume` method and why in both classes?

The commented code is all the pause/resume methods.

```
public class RandomCircles extends Activity {

    MySurfaceView mySurfaceView;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mySurfaceView = new MySurfaceView(this);
        setContentView(mySurfaceView);
    }


 /*   @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        mySurfaceView.onResumeMySurfaceView();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        mySurfaceView.onPauseMySurfaceView();
    }*/

    class MySurfaceView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable{

        Thread thread = null;
        SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
        volatile boolean running = false;

        private Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        Random random;

        public MySurfaceView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            surfaceHolder = getHolder();
            random = new Random();
        }

        /*public void onResumeMySurfaceView(){
            running = true;
            thread = new Thread(this);
            thread.start();
        }

        public void onPauseMySurfaceView(){
            boolean retry = true;
            running = false;
            while(retry){
                try {
                    thread.join();
                    retry = false;
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }*/

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            while(running){
                if(surfaceHolder.getSurface().isValid()){
                    Canvas canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
                    //... actual drawing on canvas

                    int x = random.nextInt(getWidth());

                    if(getWidth() - x < 100)
                        x -= 100;
                    else if(getWidth() - x > getWidth() - 100)
                        x += 100;

                    int y = random.nextInt(getHeight());

                    if(getHeight() - y < 100)
                        y -= 100;
                    else if(getHeight() - x > getHeight() - 100)
                        y += 100;

                    int radius;
                    radius = 100;
                    Paint paint = new Paint();
                    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
                    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                    canvas.drawPaint(paint);
                    // Use Color.parseColor to define HTML colors
                    paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#CD5C5C"));
                    canvas.drawCircle(x, y, radius, paint);

                    surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I doubt you need both. onResume makes sense, though. It makes sense since otherwise you thread is not started. I assume you didn't write this code?

Comment: I did not but I'm trying to understand why it works

Comment: So i started adding/taking away things to see what would happen

Comment: your surfaceview implements `Runnable`. for the `run` method to run, you either need to call it, or to have a `Thread` do that for you. If you remove the Thread, which is in `onResumeMySurfaceView`, it does not do anything anymore...

Comment: Ok so onResume calls onResumeMySurfaceView which starts the thread that calls the run method?

Comment: yes, that's what threads do. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two `onPause()` and `onResume()` methods are part of the `Activity` life cycle and are invoked when the `Activity` is paused/resumed.

This image illustrates the Android `Activity` life cycle. You can read up on it [HERE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

[image]

The reason it works with the additional `onResume` and `onPause` methods in your `Activity` is because you invoke your `SurfaceView` `onPauseMySurfaceView()` and `onResumeMySurfaceView()` methods from the respective methods in the `Activity`. If you didn't do that, your `SurfaceView` methods would never have been called and thus never stopped/started the thread.

Comment: But I don't have onDestroy or onStop methods, are those automatic or not needed?

Comment: They are implemented in the Activity class that you extend. You only Override them if you need to use them

Comment: What do the parent functions do for onResume and onPause?

Comment: They do Activity specific things that you don't have to worry about. All you need to remember when Overriding them is to call super.onResume(); or super.onPause(); so that the Activity methods are still executed